# Unresponsive html ul list

Tags: html

I have to code a basic html website that is responsive. I have used this code before and it worked so I am unsure what is wrong now. If anyone could help that would be amazing.

```
   <ul>
      <li> <a herf="#section1"> Exciting Toronto Activities</a></li>
      <li> <a herf="#section2"> Unique Restaurants & Bars</a></li>
      <li> <a herf="#section3"> Outdoor Adventures</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Typo: You want href. Not herf. But that has nothing to do with being responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Just a typo, you wrote `herf`. Change it to `href` and it'll work fine.

```
<ul>
   <li> <a href="#section1"> Exciting Toronto Activities</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#section2"> Unique Restaurants & Bars</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#section3"> Outdoor Adventures</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much! it worked! Such a simple mistake haha